# looping through a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

```
player_A    score Player_A  player_B    score_Player B
MP22    3   MP02    2
MP30    1   MP22    3
MP02    3   MP20    2
MP22    3   MP01    2
MP30    3   MP18    0
MP02    3   MP03    2
MP12    1   MP20    3
MP01    3   MP14    0
MP22    3   MP07    1
MP23    2   MP18    3
MP26    0   MP30    3
MP02    3   MP28    2
MP03    3   MP13    2
MP16    1   MP12    3
MP15    1   MP20    3
```

hi everyone, above is my csv file which i am trying to loop through row column 1 and 3. it about a tennis game. whoever has 3 as result i want to be able rank them; who has won most games in a descending order. thanks for your help in advance. The code below wont perform the task.

```
fp = open("DADSA COURSEWORK A TAC1 ROUND ONE men.csv")
#
fp.readline()
#for the final position.
s = fp.readline().rstrip().split()
if int(s[1]) > int(s[3]):
    listofranking.append(s[0])
    listofranking.append(s[2])
else:
    listofranking.append(s[2])
    listofranking.append(s[0])
#positioning for the semi.
for i in range(2):
    s = fp.readline().rstrip().split()
    if int(s[1]) > int(s[3]):
        listofranking.append(s[0])

    else:
        listofranking.append(s[2])

#positioning for the quater round.
for i in range(4):
    s = fp.readline().rstrip().split()
    if int(s[1]) > int(s[3]):
        listofranking.append(s[0])

    else:
        listofranking.append(s[2])
#positioning for the last 16
for i in range(8):
    s = fp.readline().rstrip().split()
    if int(s[1]) > int(s[3]):
        listofranking.append(s[0])

    else:
        listofranking.append(s[2])
    print(i)
    print(s)
```

Comment: Umm... How is that CSV? There are no commas... Looks like it's TSV (tab-separated values). If so, TSV can be parsed by the `csv` module, and you should avoid reinventing the wheel here; let `csv.reader` do the work for you; the [`excel_tab`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel_tab) dialect will probably cover you.

Comment: because it is in an excel file